# Can 'no-brainer' mean 'so we don't have to use our brains'?

Tags: expressions

Real life example: at work (software) we decided to use a tool (StyleCop) to ensure all coders conformed to the same set of coding style rules, using all the supplied rules out of the box. So, while we could have employed our collective brain-power (plus time and effort) to come up with our own rules and figure out a process to enforce them as much as possible, we instead decided to just deploy the off-the-shelf tool and get back to coding.

So was our decision to defer to a tool, rather than use our own brains, a 'no-brainer'?

Comment: ***no-brainer***: 
n. Informal
Something, especially a choice or decision, that is so obvious or easy as to require little or no thought. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/no-brainer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not in the way I have ever heard the phrase used. It's about the amount of brain-power (supposedly) needed to make the decision, not about the result of the decision.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, definitely, but not too many people would agree with you.

It's a mindless expression that mindless people use mindlessly. "It's a no-brainer."

Popular belief holds that a ***no-brainer*** is a "decision that is so disgustingly obvious, so painfully obvious, so right-there-in-front-of-your-cretinous-face, that making it requires no mental effort," i.e. no thinking is necessary.

Most people will agree that your ***choice*** in favor of the ready-made rule book was a no-brainer.

They will agree to it without realizing that there are *further implications*.

They will embrace it mindlessly, unaware that the expression can, if need be, stand for something other than "a mindless choice."

Case in point: Some folks believe (mindlessly) that the word "close" (one of the options when you open up a question post on EL&U) stands for "close this question because I feel like showing the OP I have power over them, and I don't like his question - at all." It's a no-brainer for them to click that option.

I dare not go on. Next question, please.

Comment: For the record, I am not the one who close-voted this question. But why not delete the last part?

Comment: If "popular belief" holds that an expression means something, then **by definition** the expression means that, whether you approve of it or not. It is possible that it also means other things (and it may well be that some people use it only in those other meanings)., I don't completely understand what the other meaning is that you are claiming for ''no-brainer'', but I think it is intended to be insulting: I don't recall ever hearing the expression used in that way.